# RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException when using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types with Dapper

Tags: .net, sql-server, dapper

Using a Sql Server Data Tools project whose target platform is set to one of:

- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server 2014

And deploying to (localdb)\Projects or (localdb)\ProjectsV12

Calling a stored procedure that returns a Geometry, Geography or HierachyId type such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectSqlGeometry]
    @x Geometry
AS
    SELECT @x as y
RETURN 0
```

The following calling code:

```
var result = Connection.Query("dbo.SelectSqlGeometry", new { x = geometry }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
bool isSame = ((bool)geometry.STEquals(result.y));
```

results in the following exception on the STEquals line.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException
>   was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=An
>   unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation
>   Source=Microsoft.CSharp   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args,
>   DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
>          at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1
>   arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
>          at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpConvertBinder.FallbackConvert(DynamicMetaObject
>   target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
>          at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
>          at System.Dynamic.ConvertBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
>          at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1
>   site, Object[] args)
>          at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)
>          at DATailor.Examples.Dapper.SqlClient.Test.AllTypesDAOTest.TestAllTypesDynamic()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the root cause is not Dapper, there is an underlying exception that is being swallowed.

Using ADO.Net code like:

```
var geometry = Util.CreateSqlGeometry();
SqlDataReader reader=null;
SqlCommand cmd=null;
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectSqlGeometry", (SqlConnection)Connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@x", geometry) { UdtTypeName = "Geometry" });
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var y = (SqlGeometry)reader.GetValue(0);
        var same = geometry.STEquals(y);
    }
    reader.Dispose();
    reader = null;
}
finally
{
    if (reader != null)
    {
        if (!reader.IsClosed) try { cmd.Cancel(); }
            catch {}
        reader.Dispose();
    }
    if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

The following exception is thrown at `reader.GetValue`

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467262
>   Message=[A]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry cannot be cast to
>   [B]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry. Type A originates from
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'.
>   Source=DynamicGeometryIssue   StackTrace:
>          at DynamicGeometryIssue.TestDao.TestGeometry() in c:\Users\rich\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\DynamicGeometryIssue\DynamicGeometryIssue\TestDao.cs:line
>   27
>          at DynamicGeometryIssue.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\rich\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\DynamicGeometryIssue\DynamicGeometryIssue\Program.cs:line
>   15
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

The cause of the underlying exception is a known breaking change in SQL Server 2012.  See the **SQL CLR Data Types**  section of the following MSDN documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=sql.110).aspx

The resolution, that has worked for me is to create the following bindingRedirect in the app.config or web.config.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types"
                      publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"
                      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0"
                     newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Alternately, with .NET 4.5 you can change your connection string to include a value of "SQL Server 2012" for the "Type System Version" attribute to force SqlClient to load version 11.0 of the assembly.

Another workaround is code like:

```
var geo = SqlGeography.Deserialize(rdr.GetSqlBytes(0));
```

However, I don't believe this is an option with Dapper.