# Cannot read SqlGeography with Dapper

Tags: dapper, sqlgeography

I followed alot of SO questions and I am getting simillar error but I cannot fix this issue.

My Dapper version is 1.50.1
My Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version is 11.0.2

I have added binding redirect in configuration file as follows:

```
<runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

The error I get is:

> Error parsing column 2 (Location=POINT (-122.349 47.651) - Object)

While the inner exception is:

> [A]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll'.

If I just do a read to dynamic object everything is all right but if I do read to my own type that has SqlGeography I get this error.

I thought I did all as recommended but it seems I missed something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException when using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600043/runtimebinderinternalcompilerexception-when-using-microsoft-sqlserver-types-with)

Comment: Possible duplicate of my own answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=sql.110).aspx) on topic **SQL CLR Data Types (geometry, geography, and hierarchyid)**.

Alternatively, try adding this in your connectionString:

"Type System Version=SQL Server 2012", to force SqlClient to load version 11.0 of the assembly

Answer (score 1):

@Marc Gravell did a good job about that see reference below and it will save your life.

[SqlGeography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440784/dapper-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-microsoft-sqlserver-types-sqlgeography-to)

[Issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/570)

For ASP.NET applications, add the following line of code to the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

For desktop applications, add the following line of code to run before any spatial operations are performed:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

The `.LoadNativeAssemblies` method will get the correct assembly for you base on CPU architecture.

In bin folder you should have this.

[image]